# creating links containing anchors

Tags: 8, uri, navigation

In relation to Drupal 8 ... if a user wanted to create a link such as the following:

```
<a href='#' onClick='testfunction ();'>link</a>
```

How could such a link be created, normally creating a link requires the use of the Url object and so the symbol '#' can't normally be used, nor can 'javascript:void (0)'.

Essentially I'm trying to create an link with an anchor tag in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Url component is not able to generate URLs with empty anchors, so you need  create an anchor on your page or use existing one.

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$url = Url::fromUserInput('#main-content');
print Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Link text'), $url)->toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Digging it up to provide a broader approach. As per the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.9.x), one can use the "fragment" option in order to attach an anchor (#) to a drupal Link.

e.g.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Link;

$url = Url::fromRoute('example.route', ['route_parameter' => 'example'], ['fragment' => 'anchor-section']);
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Link with anchor'), $url);
```